# Classpath VS Target folder in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build, classpath

I know that the classpath is a list of directories and .jar files where the ClassLoader will try to look for class files. But I'm not sure how is it initialized? For example in a Spring Boot application can target folder be considered the classpath of the project? If not, when the classpath is created? And I also know that everything from the resources folder is copied in the classpath but why? why is it necessary if the classpath is searched only for compiled java files (class files)? I would like a deeply explanation of all these concepts because it's confusing..

Comment: Are we talking about build time or runtime?

Comment: Well..both of them

Comment: The classpath in general is handled by the JVM (runtime) or javacompiler (buildtime)... The resource directory is copied based on the reason that it might be filtered etc. furthermore to get a single location in the end which is used as part of the classpath... (target/classes) or (target/test-classes)...